# Validate expression is not working in Internet Explorer 6 while working fine in I.E 8 and 9

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a change password page and on this page I have a regular expression validator as shown below

```
  <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="StrongPasswordValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtNewPassword"
                            Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="New password must be from 8 to 50 characters long.It must contain atleast one digit and one uppercase.It cannot contain spaces &amp; letters like /\'?&gt;,&quot;|"
                            meta:resourcekey="StrongPasswordValidatorResource1" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationExpression="^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*[\s\\'?>/,&quot;|]).{8,50}$"
                            ValidationGroup="ChangePassword"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

validation Expression is working fine in I.E 8 and 9 but not working in I.E 6, Could anyone help me please???

Comment: Give up on IE 6. Please. Microsoft has done it, and you should too.

Comment: Its not about me its about users please any clue...

Comment: @BASEERHAIDER - You chose to use a Microsoft technology to develop your application and considering they no longer consider IE6 a viable solution, I would say your out of luck.

Comment: Instead of RegularExpressionValidator u can use Javascript validating Functions.It's Better to you it will work all browsers without any problem.

Comment: @R1 - That is a *very* broad statement. I'd be careful about how you use the term *all browsers*.

Comment: @BASEERHAIDER - invest your time in something more productive than getting this one thing to work for a browser that a tiny % of your users will be using

Comment: Can any body please solve this issue?????????? Please.....!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there is a issue of length in I.E 6 it is not identifying the length so in order to deal with this issue I use custom validator with a JavaScript and uses a String.length property to over come length issue so now it is working perfectly in I.E 6 as well.